# Can't updateMany values using azure function - nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to use updateMany and update the JSON object filled with `_id` and set the field `winnerHasBeenNotified` to true, but if I `console.log(listing)`, then I'm getting `nModified: 0`

I added a patch, put, and post to the function.json just in case. The body is being passed as you can see in the output below, but it never updates and I don't know why.

Why is that?

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;



module.exports = async function (context, req) {


  MongoClient.connect(process.env.CosmosDBConnectionString, async (err, client) => {


    let listingId = ({ _id } = req.body);

    console.log("listing ID Value");
    console.log(listingId);
    let send = response(client, context);

    if (err) send(500, err.message);

    let db = client.db(process.env.dbName);


    const listing = await db.collection('listings').updateMany({ _id: listingId._id },
      {
        $set: { winnerHasBeenNotified: true }
      })

    //console.log(listing);
    if (!listing) {
      console.log("LISTING FAILED TO UPDATE")

      send(401, { message: "Something Went Wrong" });

    }
    else {
      console.log("LISTING HAS BEEN UPDATED")

      context.res = await { status: 200 };
    }

  })
}




function response(client, context) {
  return function (status, body) {
    context.res = {
      status: status,
      body: body
    };

    client.close();
    context.done();
  };
}
```

```
[3/24/2020 6:13:39 PM]   "method": "POST",
[3/24/2020 6:13:39 PM]   "uri": "/api/SetWinnerHasBeenNotifiedToTrue",
[3/24/2020 6:13:39 PM]   "identities": [
[3/24/2020 6:13:39 PM]     {
[3/24/2020 6:13:39 PM]       "type": "WebJobsAuthLevel",
[3/24/2020 6:13:39 PM]       "level": "Admin"
[3/24/2020 6:13:39 PM]     }
[3/24/2020 6:13:39 PM]   ],
[3/24/2020 6:13:39 PM]   "status": 200,
[3/24/2020 6:13:39 PM]   "duration": 58
[3/24/2020 6:13:39 PM] }
[3/24/2020 6:13:40 PM] listing ID Value
[3/24/2020 6:13:40 PM] [ { _id: '5e7948797d1b94622cebaab1' },
[3/24/2020 6:13:40 PM]   { _id: '5e7a325a38c8e58ee8fe39a3' },
[3/24/2020 6:13:40 PM]   { _id: '5e7a334438c8e58ee8fe39ab' } ]
[3/24/2020 6:13:40 PM] LISTING HAS BEEN UPDATED
[3/24/2020 6:13:42 PM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000179CDB79'.
```

function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post",
        "patch",
        "put"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

UPDATE:

So one thing I realized was I needed to put mongoose.Types.ObjectId() around the IDs and use string array instead of JSON object.

So this

```
      ["5e7ac19c6b3a266e8c612765",
        "5e7ac1cd6b3a266e8c612766",
        "5e7ac1f06b3a266e8c612767"
      ];
```

intead of

```
 [ { _id: '5e7948797d1b94622cebaab1' },
 { _id: '5e7a325a38c8e58ee8fe39a3' },
  { _id: '5e7a334438c8e58ee8fe39ab' } ]
```

I have an working example of me using `updateMany` with a string array so that was the format I used that worked for me. With the `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` I'm able to findOneAndUpdate. I wasn't able to before inside azure function, but I still can't get `updateMany` working in azure function. It sends status 200, but nothing updates with `updateMany`
Here's my updated code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


module.exports = async function (context, req) {


  MongoClient.connect(process.env.CosmosDBConnectionString, async (err, client) => {


    let auctionIds =
      ["5e7ac19c6b3a266e8c612765",
        "5e7ac1cd6b3a266e8c612766",
        "5e7ac1f06b3a266e8c612767"
      ];
    console.log("listing ID Value");
    //console.log(listingId);
    let send = response(client, context);

    if (err) send(500, err.message);

    let db = client.db(process.env.dbName);


    db
      .collection('listings')
      .updateMany(
        { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(auctionIds) },
        { $set: { winnerHasBeenNotified: true } },
        (err, res) => {
          if (err) send(500, err.message);

          send(200, res);
        }
      );


  });


};


function response(client, context) {
  return function (status, body) {
    context.res = {
      status: status,
      body: body
    };

    client.close();
    context.done();
  };
}
```

Comment: `_id` will only match 1 document, so if that document already has `winnerHasBeenNotified: true`, the mongod won't actually do any writing, the original document won't be modified, and the the retuned `nModified` will be zero.

Comment: I have an example that looks identical to my ```UPDATE``` in code above. It uses a string array of Ids and it updates all the matching documents. So I was originally wrong in how I set it up I think, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work. Here's an identical working example I have of using ```UpdateMany``` in the same format + it's output:  https://pastebin.com/xHxiGsrp Why does this code work and my ```winnerHasBeenNotified``` code doesn't?

Comment: does ` { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(auctionIds) }` automatically use the `$in` operator, or does it look for a single document that has an array of ObjectID for an `_id`?

Comment: If I set it up like ```{ _id: {$in: auctionIds} }``` Then I get status 200, but nothing updates
If I set it up like ```{ _id: { $in: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(auctionIds) } }``` I get ```Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters```